# SWT Thread.sleep inside a run() + KeyListener

Tags: java, multithreading, swt, keylistener

So, im trying to make a little game with a small spaceship that is controllable trough a KeyListener.
Since SWT needs the Main Thread trapped in order to update the UI i wanted to use a Thread which i can programm enemys for the spaceship to fight with.

I wanted to build in a Timer with Thread.sleep() so the enemy can move in a specific way, but my Problem now is that when i try to use Thread.sleep() inside the run(), or even leave the Thread without a Thread.sleep() the whole UI slows down significant. It seems that the KeyListener cant make any actions till the Thread.sleep() is over.

This is my Code for the Enemy Thread right now:

```
display.asyncExec(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                switch(enemyrandomize())
                {
                    
                    case 0:
                        casualenemy();
                        
                        break;
                        
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
```

This works perfectly fine but if i put the Thread.sleep() inside or under the casualenemy() method it will make the problem as said.

I also tried that:

```
Thread operationThread = new Thread() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                while (true) 
                {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    
                    display.asyncExec(new Runnable() 
                    {
                        public void run() 
                        {
                            switch(enemyrandomize())
                            {
                                
                                case 0:
                                    casualenemy();
                                    
                                    break;
                                    
                                default:
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        };
```

That works for some sort but then i can only put a timer outside of the run() where i want it to be.
Any Ideas?

Comment: Sorry but this really is not clear enough. Note that display.asyncExec runs code in the UI thread, anything you call there must **not** call Thread.sleep

Comment: Ok. Let me try it another way.  Is it possible to set the Display.timerExec() inside the run() ?

Comment: DIsplay.timerExec can be called from anywhere in the UI thread. It is not allowed in other threads.

Comment: It is probably better to not use the Thread at all but only Display.timerExec(). You can chain them. Call Display.timerExec(1000, your-enemy-code) and at the end of the your-enemy-code block you call Display.timerExec(1000, your-enemy-code) again. This way your enemy code will be executed every second without blocking the main thread.